# AJAX or WebSockets for a Heartstone-like game?

Tags: ajax, web, websocket, server, client

Game is a one-vs-one turn based 2D card management game to be played in a browser.

It is very much like Hearstone where a player plays a number of cards, observes effects and then passes turn to the opponent.

Game mechanics and prototype are ready and I need to decide on technology.

Server is PHP + MySQL, heard of node.js but have no experience with it.

I cannot have loss of packets, so need to use HTTP I guess.

Initial idea is to have scheduled AJAX call every 5 seconds to get game state for each client to check for:

- end of turn
- change of game state (and render animation based on it)

Obviously I would also need to validate every action of an active player on the server.

I am concerned of the number of calls to my server (not an expensive hosting) and how many calls would a modest server be capable of handling...

As a plus of Ajax I see guaranteed packet delivery and no issues with proxies involved (which may cut persistent connections).

Answer (score 0):

Websockets reduce latency and server workload ( no need to open a new connection, meaning a key exchange in case of https), provided that you interact frequently.

A great advantage is that you are able to 'push' a message to the client (as opposed to having to 'pull' via Ajax every few seconds.

The server language shouldn't be a problem, but if you plan to maintain / extend it, you should choose carefully (I'm guessing you're a rather new programmer, thus gaining experience in a better suited environment would not be a huge amount of work).

Edit: just to clarify, I would recommend the usage of a websocket for your use case